# transformation matrix by a point and normalvector

Tags: matlab, vector, frame, plane

I need to define some points on a 3D plain in matlab.

The plane goes through an point P[2 5 3] with an normal vector of [0.577 0577 0577]. Is there a way to get an transformation matrix out of the normal vector related to the basis frame, so that I can transform some point to it?

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do with the transformation matrix here. Are you trying to project a 3D point into that 2D plane?

Comment: May this be more a mathematical question? Have a look at the dot product or [here](https://sites.math.washington.edu/~king/coursedir/m445w04/notes/vector/normals-planes.html)